# What is the return of an UPDATE query?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm using `sqlalchemy` in combination with `sqlite` and the `databases` library and I'm trying to wrap my head around what that combination returns when doing update queries. I'm running a testcase and I have sqlalchemy set up to roll back upon execution of each testcase via `force_rollback=True`.

```py
db = databases.Database(DB_URL, force_rollback=True)


query = update(my_table).where(my_table.columns.id == some_id_to_update).values(**values)
res = await db.execute(query)
```

When working with `psql`, I'd expect `res` to be the number of rows that were affected by the `UPDATE` query, but from reading the documentation, `sqlite` seems to behave differently in that it doesn't return anything. I tested this manually by connecting to the database via `sqlite3` and as expected, there is no return when doing `UPDATE` queries. `sqlalchemy` however does return something, which I assume is the number of total rows in the table, but I'm not sure. Can anybody shed some light into what is actually returned?

What's more, when I tried to get the number of rows affected by the `UPDATE` query via `SELECT changes()`, I'm also getting the number of total rows in the table and not the rows affected by the most recent query. Do I have a misunderstanding of what `changes()` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The [changes() function](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#changes) returns the number of database rows that were changed or inserted or deleted by the most recently completed INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement, exclusive of statements in lower-level triggers."

When you use the Python *sqlite3* module, you use *.executeXXX* interfaces to evaluate/prepare your query. If the query is supposed to modify the database, it does it at this stage. You have to use the same interface to prepare a SELECT statement. In either case, the *.executeXXX* interfaces never return anything. To get the result of a SELECT query, you have to use a *.fetchXXX* interface after running *.executeXXX*.

To get the number of changed rows after INSERT, DELETE, or UPDATE statement via *sqlite3*, you can also take the difference in *con.total_changes* before/after running *.executeXXX*.

Comment: Well, I feel like an idiot. I did indeed use `db.execute` when instead I should have used `db.fetch_val`. Thanks! I still think it is weird that `db.execute` always returns the number of rows in the table, but so be it.